# android studio prevent past date in datepicker kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-datepicker

How can I disable only past date days from datepicker and not the future? I know it is somewhere around the startCalendar.set but I can't find the setMinValue.

```
/* Calendar Start Date Button Click */
        startdatepicker = findViewById(R.id.CalendarStartImage)
        startdateview = findViewById(R.id.StartDateTextView)
        val startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        val startPicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ view, year, month,dayOfMonth ->
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year)
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month)
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth)
            

            updateStartCalendar(startCalendar)
        }
        startdatepicker.setOnClickListener{
            DatePickerDialog(this,startPicker,startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
        }
```

Comment: I think dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(long minDate) may help. 
If it's not, you can try to create a custom Dialog with DatePicker widget and set minDate in xml. According to documentation: "android:minDate
The minimal date shown by this calendar view in mm/dd/yyyy format."

Comment: may i know which line should i add in the setMinDate ? cant seems to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing content of setOnClickListener with this something like this

```
val dialog = DatePickerDialog(this,startPicker, startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
dialog.datePicker.minDate = startCalendar.getTimeInMillis()
dialog.show()
```